# Why are Some golang.org Packages Prefixed with an `x`

Tags: go, cryptography, package

Why are some golang.org package names prefixed with an `x`?  The specific package that piqued my interest [was bycrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto)

My main concern is the `x` means something like e**X**perimental, and I should use a different set of libraries if I want something stable.  If not that, the `x` is there to signify something -- I'm  curious what it is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `x` means external. They are developed outside of the golang core.  Experimental packages are under `golang.org/x/exp`

Refs:
https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/eD8dh3T9yyA/l5Ail-xfMiAJ

Comment: `exp` refers to experimental. While I don't have a reference for what the `x` stands for I do have a reference showing that they aren't experimental:
https://go.dev/wiki/X-Repositories

I've seen the `x` referred to as `extra` in Go chat rooms & communities like the Discord.

Answer (score 7):

Packages that are prefixed with X are part of the go project but are stored in sub repos. They are not experimental.

See: https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo